# Using structures in other structures. C

Tags: c, struct, structure, typedef

I have three structures in one .h file.

```
typedef struct name{
      char first[20];
      char middle;
      char last[20];
    } PersonName;

typedef struct address{
      char street[20];
      char city[20];
      char state[20];
      int zipCode;
        } PersonAddress;

typedef struct employee{
      PersonName bob;
      PersonAddress place;
      int id;
    } Employee;
```

And what I'm trying to do is use the employee structure to do the work of the other structures.

I have a call:

```
     void setName(struct employee* object, char* f, char* l, char* m);
```

to my .c file which is supposed to receive this at:

```
 void setName(struct employee* object, char* f, char* l, char* m){
        strncpy(object.bob.first,f,20);
        strncpy(object.bob.last,l, 20);
        object.bob.middle=m[0];

    }
```

To be able to change the values without using the other structures. Am I just looking at it the wrong way? CMD says "Request for bob in something not a structure.
Any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `object` is a pointer to a struct, not a struct itself. Therefore you need to use `->` to access the members, not `.`.

Comment: object is a pointer to a structure. Try object->bob instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bob is a pointer. In order to access its members, try using the -> operator instead of .

In other words:

```
void setName(struct employee* object, char* f, char* l, char* m){
  strncpy(object->bob.first,f,20);
  strncpy(object->bob.last,l, 20);
  object->bob.middle=m[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

object is a pointer, hence you need to type object->bob to access bob.
bob is a struct, so you need object->bob.first to access first.

Also, you might want to replace all those 20 by a constant before you need to change them, forget to change one, and have bugs all over the place.

Comment: Rather than using a a literal constant you might want to use a sizeof expression.  This will allow your code to automatically track changes in in the structure definition. something along the lines of           #define member_size(type, member) sizeof(((type *)0)->member)